# show bootstrap modal after Request[]

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a modal with `bootstrap` in `mvc4`. But whenever I call a Request[] the form disappears.

I've tried this:

```
@{
    bool show = false;

    if(Request["btn"] == "click here")
    {
        show = true;
    }
}

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#form_login">Login</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="form_login" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="form_loginLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="form_loginLabel">Test form</h4>
            </div> <!-- class="modal-header" -->

            <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div> <!-- class="modal-body" -->

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btn" id="login_submit" class="button" />
                </div> <!-- class="modal-footer" -->
            </form>
        </div> <!-- class="modal-content" -->
    </div> <!-- class="modal-dialog" -->
</div> <!-- id="form_login" -->

<script>
    @{
        if(showModal)
        {
            $('#form_login').modal("show");
        }
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't work however. What would be a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: do you want this to fire off of a button click or a value passed from the controller?

Comment: @MattBodily - A button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

This has to be edited:
From

```
<script>
    @{
        if(showModal)
        {
            $('#form_login').modal("show");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Into

```
<script>
    @{
        if(showModal)
        {
            <text>$('#form_login').modal("show");</text>
        }
    }
</script>
```